# Boolean logic (ab+a'+b')cd

Tags: boolean-algebra

I can't find an example of this anywhere. So I know that is returns cd but I'm curious on the steps. If I do ab+a' first then I'm left with (a'+b+b')cd => a'cd. If I do ab+b' first then I'm left with (a+b')cd. So what step am I missing here? Do I add something to the equation to make it so everything in the parentheses disappears?

Comment: a' + b + b' = a + 1 = 1

Comment: ah, im dumb. ty